# Power set of set of all integers $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be the set $\{ x\in \mathbb Z\, |\, x \le -2 \; \text{or} \; x \ge 5 \}$.

What is $P(S) \cap \{\{-3,-2,1\},\{4\},\{6,7\},\{-5,6,9\}\}$?

That is the question, how do I find the power set of $S$, $P(S)$?

I can do the rest but I am not sure what the power set $P(S)$ is.

Comment: The power set of $S$ is the collection of all subsets of $S$. You do not need to "find" the power set, per se, but rather decide which of the sets $\{-3, -2, 1\}$, $\{4\}$, etc. also belong to the power set of $S$.

Comment: We have $x\in P(S)$ if and only if for every $y \in x$ we have $y\le -2 \ or\  y\ge 5$. The first two sets in the brackets do not fulfill this property, but the last two do. So, the elements of the desired set are the last two sets.

Comment: @Peter, I think you meant to type that $x\in P(S)$ if and only if for every $y\in x$, $y\leq -2$ or $y\geq 5$.

Comment: This exercise is asking you: which of the following sets ($\{ -3, -2, -1\} ...$ and the other three) are contained in $S$ (i.e. are subsets of $S$, i.e. belong to $P(S)$)?

Comment: The answer is {{$6,7$},{$-5,6,9$}}.

Comment: The powerset of S is uncountably infinite.  but just like you don't have to "find" Z to know that Z $\cap$ {5,27, $\pi$, 27/3} is {5,27}, you don't need to find the power set.  In the case with Z you just need to know which of those four are integers.  In your problem, you just need to know which of those four are subsets of S.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments (by Austin Mohr), you don't need an 'explicit description' of $\mathcal P(S)$.

It is a basic fact that $A\cap B\subseteq B$. So we have that $$\mathcal P(S) \cap \big\{\{-3,-2,1\},\{4\},\{6,7\},\{-5,6,9\}\big\}\subseteq \big\{\{-3,-2,1\},\{4\},\{6,7\},\{-5,6,9\}\big\} $$

Now, is $\{-3,-2,1\}\in \mathcal P(S)$? Well, this happens if and only if $\{-3,-2,1\}\subseteq S$, that is, all of $-3,-2$ and $1$ are in $S$. From you definition of $S$ we see that $1\not\in S$, so $\{-3,-2,1\}\not\in \mathcal P (S)$.

The same reasoning should be used for the others.